# DataTables - Dynamically created footer not fixed

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables and since the data can change on the fly I'm having to destroy and re-initialize my table.  The columns can be different each time so I need to dynamically create the footer like so:

```
   "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                        var api = this.api(), data;
                        //dynamically create footer
                        var footer = $(this).append('<tfoot><tr id="frow"></tr></tfoot>');

                        var intVal = function (i) {
                            return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
                        };
                        var numFormat = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2).display;

                        var i = 0
                        this.api().columns().every(function () {
                            var total = api.column(i, { search: 'applied' }).data().reduce(function (a, b) { return intVal(a) + intVal(b); }, 0);
                            $('#frow').append('<th>' + numFormat(total) + '</th>');
                            i++;
                        });
 }
```

All that works fine but the footer isn't fixed.  I tried setting the fixed footer during initialization but only the header is correctly fixed:

```
fixedHeader: {
                header: true,
                footer: true,
                headerOffset: $('.navbar').outerHeight(),
                footerOffset: $('.footer').outerHeight()
             }
```

I also tried setting the fixed footer after initialization but again only the header was fixed:

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table, {
    footer: true
} );
```

Is have a dynamic fixed footer possible?